Using ShareReplay() and to cache result of observable - how to refresh and use new value in another observable
I am using shareReplay() to cache an http call so it isn't repeated. However, at some point, I need to refresh the API call. Following various suggestions in stackoverflow, I introduce a Subject, so something like this:
  private _refreshResponse$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);

  public response$: Observable<any> = this._refreshResponse$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl)),
    map((o) => o.message),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.response$.subscribe();
  }

  public onRefreshClick() {
    this.refreshResponse();
  }

  public refreshResponse() {
    this._refreshResponse$.next();
  }

And calling onRefreshClick() does indeed call the API again.
I introduced a new method to do some more work. I want to make an http call first, which will then call refreshResponse(), and then some work with the new value. Something like the following:
  public onDoSomeWork() {
    // just create an observable... imagine it is an http call or something
    this.fakeHttpCall()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.refreshResponse()),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.response$.pipe(
            take(1),
            tap((o) => console.log(o))
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

But, of course, refreshResponse() does not wait for the returned value, so the value I get from response$ immediately after it is the previous value, NOT the new value. How can I "wait" for the new value.
Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2dtlg . The "response" is displayed in the browser (just a url from some random API I found). If you open the console, and click the "Work" button, it will refresh the URL displayed, and also write a URL to the console.log. But the console.log value is the previous value, not the updated one.
Note: I don't want to do the "console.log" in the this.response$.subscribe(() => ...) method.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: One (awful!) solution is to add a delay:
  public onDoSomeWork() {
    // just create an observable... imagine it is an http call or something
    this.fakeHttpCall()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.refreshResponse()),
        delay(2000),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.response$.pipe(
            take(1),
            tap((o) => console.log(o))
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

This is just to show what I expect/where the problem lies if it's not clear...

would skip(1) fit your needs?

@Andrei no I don't think so. OnDoSomeWork() is linked to a button and clicked multiple times. I just kind of want a work flow where I

make "fake" http call
refresh the sharereplay observable (another http call)
wait for the refresh to complete to then continue executing the next thing in the pipe


i would make the response as this: response$ = ...switchMap(() => merge(of(null), makeRequest())), shareReplay(1), filter(Boolean). this way nulls will be sareReplayed, but filtered out for subscribers. i.e. for subscribers before refresh - they would receive old value, for subs after refresh they would wait for the new value

That appears to work, thank you!
